# Disabling free text in DatePicker TextBox - but allowing delete

Tags: jquery, datepicker, readonly

I've noticed a few posts on here that disable free typing into JQuery DatePicker textboxes,
e.g.

```
$("#my_txtbox").attr( 'readOnly' , 'true' );

<input type="text" name="date" readonly="readonly" />

$("#my_txtbox").keypress(function(event) {event.preventDefault();});
```

But none allow you to delete any dates already populating the textbox. Does anyone know a way of doing this? I also need to maintain the value on postback.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I came up with was to do it yourself. This takes many steps. First, you need to disallow all keys except backspace (and perhaps delete as well) for your datepicker text input. I did this with the following code.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){ 
    var elid = $(document.activeElement).is('#yourDatepicker'); 
    if(e.keyCode === 8 && elid ){ 
        return true; //allow the backspace character
    }
    else {
        return false; //disallow all other characters
    }
});
```

This is fine, but then I noticed that the user could delete only some of the date and not all of it. I did not like this, so I decided to select the text. I had to account for text focus and a click when already in focus.

I did this with the following code:

```
//When you click the text box, select all text. 
$('#yourDatepicker').focus(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.select();

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $this.select();
    }, 1);

    // Workaround for chrome
    function mouseUpHandler() {
        $this.off("mouseup", mouseUpHandler);
        return false;
    }

    $this.mouseup(mouseUpHandler);

    //When in focus, make it so the text is still selected after a click.
    $this.click(function() {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $this.select();
        }, 1);

        // Workaround for chrome
        function mouseUpHandler() {
            $this.off("mouseup", mouseUpHandler);
            return false;
        }   
    });
});
```

Sometimes you also need to look at the case of a textbox remaining in focus after the date has been changed. I decided to take the focus off the textbox, but you could also do a similar select function as the one above. To take the focus off, you actually use datepicker's "onSelect".

For example:

```
//A date change has occurred
$('#yourDatepicker').datepicker({
    stuff: 'stuff',
    morestuff: 'moreStuff',
    onSelect: function() {
      $(this).blur(); //This takes the focus off of the textbox
    }
});
```

As said before, you can replace that function with the one used for the focus/click case. Finally, you need to account for the user trying to paste into the textbox. Here is my code:

```
//NO PASTES ALLOWED!!!!!
$('#yourDatepicker').bind('paste', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```